# How to export influxdb database to csv with RFC3339 timestamps

Tags: csv, export, influxdb, rfc3339

I would like to export my InfluxDB database to a CSV file.
Im currently using the following code:

```
$ influx -database 'Dabtabase_name' -execute 'SELECT * FROM table_name' -format csv > test.csv
```

The code works but timestamps are displayed as numbers as follows:

```
1609459200000000000
```

I would like to save it in a way where the timestamp is saved in  RFC3339 format, like this:

```
2021-01-01T00:00:00
```

Comment: When you first connect to the CLI, specify the rfc3339 precision:

$ influx -precision rfc3339

influx -precision 'rfc3339' -database 'Dabtabase_name' -execute 'SELECT * FROM table_name' -format csv > test.csv



If it works please let me know then I will add this comment to the answer.

Comment: This worked. Thank you

Comment: Can i add it to the answer

Comment: Of course. I did not understand why it was only a comment. I deleted the other one and upvoted the one you added.

Comment: Cruz Lemin Actually I posted the answer and someone has deleted it. I worked on InfluxDb 9 months before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first connect to the CLI, specify the rfc3339 precision

```
$ influx -precision rfc3339
```

To get RFC 3339  when you export to CSV use this.

```
$ influx -precision 'rfc3339' -database 'Dabtabase_name' -execute 'SELECT * FROM table_name' -format csv > test.csv
```